# How to resolve unknown issue in D3js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

My code which is supposed to show world map is not working and I pulled my last hair trying to figure out why, please help.

https://codepen.io/topabc1/pen/WNmWqmg/

```
async function Fetch() {
    const res = await fetch("https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.12.0/geodata/custom/world/world.topo.json");
    const mapData = await res.json();

    const h = 1000; // canvas height
    const w = 1000; // canvas width
    const p = 0; // canvas padding
    
    const svg = d3.select("#container").append("svg").attr("height", h).attr("width", w);
    
    const projection = d3.geoMercator().translate([w / 2, h / 2]).scale(100);
    
    const path = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);
    
    const nation = topojson.feature(mapData, mapData.objects.world).features;

    svg.selectAll(".country").data(nation).enter().append("path").attr("class", "country").attr("d", path);
}
Fetch();
```

Tried converting TOPOjson file content to GEOjson and creating paths to make a map of the world. Console displays error:  attribute d: Expected number, "...3.9587390174624,NaNL703.79277473...". (there are many errors like this, number for example)